# 1px width difference when set with percentage

Tags: html, css, html-lists, jquery-ui-resizable

I have horizontal table-like list which i'm using for jQuery resizable. The problem is that each li's width is set equally with f.e. 6%, but browser renders pixel width for "cells" with +-1px difference. This is not a problem  for data displaying, but becomes a pain in one intimate place when resizing an element along a ul with a fixed step.
So, how to force he browser to make all li-s equal? (Actually I did it with table tag, table-layout: fixed and colgroup, but unfortunately table doesn't fit all layout requirements).

Html:

```
<ul class="month-ul">
    <li class="emp-li">Name</li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
    <li class="data-li"></li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.data-li, .emp-li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.emp-li {
    width: 16%;
}

.data-li {
    width: 7%;
}
```

JsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/XVRBF/

Comment: Sounds like a rounding error. Which browser(s) are you testing with? Is it the same across all browsers?

Comment: Really strange because Chrome computed value is the same for each `<li>` but renders different widths.

Comment: OMG, looks like its Chrome issue. Firefox does the job correctly.

Comment: @liri2006 I don't think you'll be able to do anything about it. Perhaps do something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/XVRBF/1/

Comment: I was hoping that there is another way to achieve this, because i'll have a lot of those li-s, and also should the same calculations on window resize event.

Comment: @liri2006 Unfortunately, this is a bug with Chrome. If you inspect the computed value, they are all identical. For whatever reason, it's adjusting it up or down at seemingly random.

Comment: You have an error in your CSS: `width: 100;` What happens if you change that to `100px`?

Comment: @jumpingcode Yep, so, life is hard, have to do that with javascript.

Comment: @MrLister Nothing that will resolve the issue. It should be 100%.

Comment: OK, but seriously now. How wide do you want the list items to be? 27.5 pixels? Seriously, what is the width you want?

Comment: I want it to be 100% of window width, seriously.